# dynamic container size in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html

I am taking content from a text file to fill literal controls within my content placeholders. Sometimes there is more text than will fit in the container column. How can i make them dynamic, ie have scroll bars to see the unviewable content?

Answer (score 1):

If you style the container with this CSS, then scrollbars will appear when content would overflow:

```
overflow: auto;
```

Comment: works perfectly i was trying to use overflow-y and wasnt using it correctly i guess